# Fixing intersecting mesh due to sculpting?

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

I am sculpting a mesh using dynamic topology. I accidentally got an intersection between two parts of the mesh. This happened because I used the clay brush, and I "extruded" the bottom part into the top part. The problem is that it happened too long ago to be able to undo it, or revert to saved. How can I do this without losing my work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix it by applying the smooth brush with a high strength to the intersected area.